# When selecting a row in table, it switches to blank screen

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, storyboard, tableview

in part of my app (storyboard) I have a table view with various rows, and when I select a row, an html file should be displayed. Instead when I select a row, I get a blank screen instead.

I thought I needed another view controller after the tableview controller, but I get the same issue whether I have one or not.

In my table controller .m file I have the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
articleIndex = indexPath.row;

WebView *selectedArticle = [[WebView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:selectedArticle animated:YES];
[selectedArticle release];
```

That is allowing me to select a row and the screen changes to a blank one, rather than loading the relevant html file.

I have in my resources folder a .h and .m file as follows:

webView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "globals.h"
@interface WebView : UIViewController{
NSArray *articleNames;
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

webView.m

```
#import "WebView.h"
@implementation WebView
@synthesize webView;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

articleNames = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 @"chapter1",
                 @"chapter2",
                 @"chapter3",
                 @"chapter4",
                 @"chapter5",
                 @"chapter6",
                 nil] retain];

NSString *chapterName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[articleNames objectAtIndex:articleIndex]];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:chapterName ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

[chapterName release];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return YES;
}

@end
```

I can't see what I have done wrong here, any advice? I'm not sure how to get the html files to display or where I need to make changes to allow it. If I remove the HTML files from the project the app crashes so it's definitely loading them but for some reason not displaying...

Answer (score 0):

Well first off where is "articleIndex" I see you set it in your tableViewController but it is not webView.h or webView.m. I would suggest first adding in a NSLog

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSLog(@"Article URL:%@", url);
```

This will let you see if the url is correct first. Second it looks like you connected your UIWebView with interface builder, so make sure that the webView is connect correctly. You can also test the webView buy using:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.apple.com"]];
```

And see if apple.com loads. If it does then you know your issue is with your html files or the paths to them.